# What is the significance of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Consider I have a matrix $A$ of dimension $N$$\times$$M$ where $N$>$M$. I am interested to modify $A$ by the equation $A_1=A*C*pinv(D)$, where $*$ implies matrix multiplication, $pinv$ implies pseudo inverse. Matrix $C$ and $D$ are square matrix of size $M$$\times$$M$. Matrix $C=A'*A$ which we can diagonalize as  $\Sigma^M_{i=1} u_i \sigma_i v_i^t$ where $u_i$ are eigenvectors and $\sigma_i$ are corresponding eigenvalues. Now we derive matrix $D$ by the largest $k$ eigenvalues of $C$, $D = \Sigma^k_{i=1} u_i \sigma_i v_i^t$.  My question is what can we infer of $C*pinv(D)$? Is there any significance of this matrix, if such an operator is used anywhere? Any comment or suggestion or link for further reading would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it honour $P^2 = P$?

Answer (score 0):

Numerical evaluation shows that the $A_1 = \Sigma^k_{i=1} u_i \sigma_i v_i^t$,  where $u_i$ and $v_i$ are left and right singular vectors of $A$ and $\sigma_i$ are the singular values. I think it an be proved as well, but I have not tried. I am writing answer instead of deleting the post as it may be helpful to someone.